# C++ Linker Error in Constructor

Tags: c++

I keep getting Linker Error undefined reference to `Poisson::Poisson(int, int)`
I want to use `Poisson::Poisson(int, double)` as I am clearly trying to do and cannot figure out why it won't let me!

```
#include "Distribution.h"
using namespace std;

class Poisson : public Distribution
{
 public:
 // Constructors
 Poisson(int inittrials, double initlambda);
 Poisson();           //Sets trials (k) = 10, lambda = 5

 // Knowledge responsibilities
 double GetLambda() const;  
 // Returns the time zone

 double calcProb();
 double calcExpVal();
 double calcVar();



private:                                     
  double lambda;
};
```

now for my cpp file

```
#include "Poisson.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Poisson::Poisson(int inittrials, double initlambda) 
  : Distribution(inittrials)
{ 
  lambda = initlambda; 
  updateNickname("Probability of Exactly k Occurences of an event");
  updateProbEqn("f(k, lambda) = (((lambda)^k) * e(^-lambda))/ k!");
  updateExpValEqn("E(X) = Lambda");
  updateVarEqn("VAR(X) = Lambda");
}

//************************************************************

Poisson::Poisson()
{ lambda = 5.0; }

//************************************************************

double Poisson::GetLambda() const
{ return lambda; }

//************************************************************

double Poisson::calcProb()
{
   double numerator;
   double denomanator;       
   //numerator = (GetLambda())^(GetTrials()) * (2.71828183)^((-1)*GetLambda());
}

double Poisson::calcExpVal()
{
}
double Poisson::calcVar()
{
}
```

Comment: Try "Rebuild All" in your IDE (or with a makefile, "make clean").

Comment: You would need to post the code that actually causes the error. You don't have a constructor that takes `(int, int)` and somewhere that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @f00ly The linker should also tell you which translation unit is making this non-existing reference. It should give you an idea on where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Who keeps upvoting this?? It's a simple question that can't be answered with the code provided.

Comment: "undefined reference to Poisson::Poisson(int, int)"... WHERE?  Usually linkers will tell you WHERE you are referencing it, like MyCode.obj.  Then you need to post the code in MyCode.cpp that calls the Poisson ctor (could be a declared stack variable, a chainback in a derived ctor, a new call, etc.)

Comment: Voting to close after 16 hours. Without the code that causes the error, you can't answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely calling `Poisson object(4, 4)`. Since 4 is an integer, *not* a double, this will cause a linker error (as this constructor doesn't exist). Try `Poisson object(4, 4.0)` at the declaration of your objects, instead.

Comment: Actually `Poisson object(4, 4)` should work without having to explicitly use a double since the compiler should be capable of converting the integer in the second argument to a temporary double and copying that new double value into the second argument.  You can see an example here: http://ideone.com/LoMZp

Comment: With GCC, sure, but with the wording of "Linker Error:", this sounds suspiciously like a cl.exe error, which I doubt has the same brains as GCC....

Comment: if this ctor was declared "explicit" - no that only applies to ctors with 1 parameter.  Unless, it's a bug in the compiler???

Comment: It's cl.exe. The entire compiler is a bug.